# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Tags: django, flutter

```dart
factory Account.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Account(
        json["id"],
        json["email"],
        json["description"],
        json["first_name"],
        json["last_name"],
        json["phone"],
        json["username"],
        json["image"],
        json["email_confirmed"],
        json["reviews_media"] != null
            ? double.parse(json["reviews_media"])
            : (json["reviews_media"] as int).toDouble(),
        json["holiday_mode"],
        json["identity_code"],
        json["residency_city"],
        json["birthday"] != null
            ? DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(json["birthday"])
            : null);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```dart
json["reviews_media"] != null
            ? double.parse(json["reviews_media"])
            : (json["reviews_media"] as int).toDouble(),
```

If `json["reviews_media"]` is **NOT** `null` you parse it as `double` which is file, but the other part of the condition is wrong. You know that the right part is `null` you can't cast it to `int`. You should default the `null` condition to something like this :

```dart
json["reviews_media"] != null
            ? double.parse(json["reviews_media"])
            : 0.0,
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Replacing int with int? (making fields optional will resolve issue).